# How to deal with apostrophes

Tags: encoding

I'm doing an INSERT into a wordpress table and anything with an apostrophe is coming out

```
It\'s true
```

I tried using htmlspecialchars but I'm still getting the backslash.

Is there any way to write it so that the user sees

```
It's true
```

While the table in the database sees:

```
It\'s true
```

Below is my insert code:

```
global $wpdb;
                $table =    'wp_nc_location';
                $data =     array(
                            'name' => $name,
                            'street_no' => $street_number,
                            'street_name' => $street_name,
                            'city' => $city,
                            'province_state' => $province_state,
                            'postal_code' => $postal,
                            'country' => $country
                            ); 
                $format =   array(
                            '%s',
                            '%s',
                            '%s',
                            '%s',
                            '%s',
                            '%s'
                            );
                $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve the data make sure to call stripslashes, or stripslashes_deep if it's an array.

```
$name = stripslashes($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing and reading data exactly?

Are you using [`$wpdb->insert()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows) method? Which you should be doing, it takes care of escaping.

Comment: I am using $wpdb->insert()...I wonder why it isn't removing the slashes? I'll post my actual code...